# How does Chef include files generated on runtime as a template source

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, lazy-evaluation, chef-recipe, chef-template

Using Chef recipe, I am first generating a `.erb` file dynamically based on inputs from a CSV file and then I want to use that `.erb` file as a template source. But unfortunately the changes made (in `.erb` file) are not considered while the recipe is converging the resources. I also tried to use lazy evaluation but not able to figure out how to use it for the template source.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting the template documentation:

> `source`   Ruby Types: String, Array
>
> The location of a template file. By default, the chef-client looks for
>   a template file in the /templates directory of a cookbook. When the
>   local property is set to true, use to specify the path to a template
>   on the local node. This property may also be used to distribute
>   specific files to specific platforms. See “File Specificity” below for
>   more information. Default value: the name of the resource block. See
>   “Syntax” section above for more information.)

And

> ```
> local
> ```
>
> Ruby Types: TrueClass, FalseClass
>
> Load a template from a local path. By default, the chef-client loads
>   templates from a cookbook’s /templates directory. When this property
>   is set to true, use the source property to specify the path to a
>   template on the local node. Default value: false.

so what you can do is:

```
# generate the local .erb file let's say source.erb

template "/path/to/file" do
  source "/path/to/source.erb"
  local true
end
```

Your question sounds like and XY problem, reading a csv file to make a template sounds counter-productive and could probably be done with attributes and taking advantage of the `variable` attribute of `template` resource.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you know how to capture the values from the CSV file as a local variable in the recipe.

```
Examples:
 csv_hostname
 csv_fqdn
```

Here is what you do to create a template with lazy loading attributes. The following example creates a config file.

example.erb file

```
# Dynamically generated by awesome Chef so don't alter by hand.
HOSTNAME=<% @host_name %>
FQDN=<% @fqdn %>
```

recipe.rb file

```
template 'path\to\example.config' do
  source 'example.erb'
  variables(
    lazy {
      :host_name => csv_hostname,
      :fqdn => csv_fqdn
  })
end
```

If you need it to run at compile time, add the action to the block.

```
template 'xxx' do
  # blah blah
end.run_action(:create)
```